# Why GLIBC versions don't match across same amazonlinux:2 image?

Tags: rust, aws-lambda

I wanted to compile Rust on the same OS image which is used by the AWS Lambda runtime, to prevent the exact issue that I encountered below. So I cobbled together this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM amazonlinux:2

RUN yum install -y openssl-devel gcc python3 python3-pip zip make
RUN pip3 install awscli aws-sam-cli

# Install Rust toolchain using rustup
RUN curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- -y
ENV PATH="/root/.cargo/bin:${PATH}"

RUN cargo install --list

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Followed by:

`docker run -it -v "$(pwd)":/root/project -w /root/project my-rust-project sam deploy`

Everything seems to deploy fine but then my Lambda invocation fails with:

> 2023-02-27T22:47:41.378-08:00 /var/task/bootstrap: /lib64/libc.so.6:
> version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by /var/task/bootstrap)
>
> 2023-02-27T22:47:41.378-08:00 /var/task/bootstrap: /lib64/libc.so.6:
> version `GLIBC_2.18' not found (required by /var/task/bootstrap)

Inside the build container `ldd --version` prints `ldd (GNU libc) 2.26`.

**Why is an executable compiled with 2.26 looking for 2.18 or 2.25?**

Comment: That is expected. An executable compiled with a given version may use symbols from _older_ versions (for example if those symbols haven't changed). The problem is that the version of libc on the lambda is older than 2.18. If you can run `readelf -V /lib64/libc.so.6` on the lambda, it should show you the available versions.

Comment: [This github issue](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-rust-runtime/issues/17) as some interesting-sounding suggestions: Start from `amazonlinux:2017.03.1.20170812` or `lambci/lambda:build-provided`, or target `-musl`. I can't try them for you.